# Servlets and Apache Tomcat Server

Tags: java, apache, servlets, tomcat7, war

Can anyone tell me..while running servlets iam using apache tomcat. But everytime i make changes to my web application..I have to export the war file and put into the webapp directory again and again..it is too much time consuming and very hectic. For even small changes i have to export war file and then put in my webapp directory. I cant run my web application without doing this..i mean new changes are not reflected till then.. 
Isn't there any other method..i think auto deploy should do..and however it is set to true in my web application. but it is not doing it..I have been searching on the net since 2 days..but didn't got any solution..please help..

Answer (score 1):

A `WAR` file is basically just a .zip with the respective webapp contents. Instead of deploying a WAR, you can deploy an "exploded WAR", being the contents of your webapp. Various build tools support doing this, for example, Maven supports the `dir` packaging in the assembly plugin. Then, you can for example configure your project to build classes directly to your `WEB-INF/classes` directory of your "exploded WAR".

EDIT: In case it wasn't clear - you just put the exploded WAR within a directory in the webapps directory where you normally put the WARs - so instead of `application.war`, you just put an `application` directory containing the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

## IDE

You can develop with [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment?wprov=sfsi1)s like [*Eclipse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) or [*Netbeans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans). It will be easy to develop and auto-deploy will be taken care by themselves. It will save much time. And completely developed final product can be exported at final stage.

Comment: [IntelliJ by JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and [JDeveloper by Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDeveloper) are two more such IDEs that may provide good integration with web server & servlet container tools like Tomcat.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler then also problem is coming

Answer (score 1):

Most popular IDEs like `Eclipse`, `IntelliJ` or `Netbeans` provide web testing and publishing tools for users, it's a very basic feature.

In case you're using `Eclipse`, navigating to `Web Tools Platform User Guide > Using the server tools` in **help page**, should be sufficient for you to set up the environment.

Here's [online help document](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcwover.html) for Eclipse Mars, for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the IDEs nowadays can do some rapid redeployment or hot-swapping of classes. This can work for some scenarios but not all.

## JRebel

For even more advanced hot-swapping in more scenarios, consider the commercial tool [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) by ZeroTurnAround.com.